# How to reset in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a App with a QRCode Scanner and React Navigation. After navigating from the QRScanner to another screen the QRScanner is still active. I found out, that I have to reset my Navigator with StackActions (right?). I tried it with this in my success screen (which comes after the QRScanner):

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 3,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'VerificationSuccess' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

But it doesn't work. Unfortunately, I could find any tutorial... 
This is my navigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import VerificationScreen from './VerificationScreen';
import QRScanner from './QRScanner';
import ChatG from '../ChatG';
import VerificationSuccess from './VerificationSuccess';

export default createStackNavigator(
    {
        VerificationScreen: {
            screen: VerificationScreen,
        },
        QRScanner: {
            screen: QRScanner,
        },
        VerificationSuccess: {
            screen: VerificationSuccess,
        },
        ChatG: {
            screen: ChatG,
        }
    }
);
```

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be familiar with SwitchNavigator yet. The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time.

Use switchStackNavigator as below:

```
const AppStack = AppStackNavigator;
const AuthStack = AuthStackNavigator;

export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "AuthLoading"
  }
);
```

Full working example below,

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {
      ActivityIndicator,
      AsyncStorage,
      Button,
      StatusBar,
      StyleSheet,
      View,
    } from 'react-native';
    import { StackNavigator, SwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json

    class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Please sign in',
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
          </View>
        );
      }

      _signInAsync = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
      };
    }

    class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Welcome to the app!',
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Show me more of the app" onPress={this._showMoreApp} />
            <Button title="Actually, sign me out :)" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
          </View>
        );
      }

      _showMoreApp = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Other');
      };

      _signOutAsync = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.clear();
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
      };
    }

    class OtherScreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Lots of features here',
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="I'm done, sign me out" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
            <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
          </View>
        );
      }

      _signOutAsync = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.clear();
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
      };
    }

    class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this._bootstrapAsync();
      }

      // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
      _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
        const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

        // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
        // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
        this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
      };

      // Render any loading content that you like here
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
            <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });

    const AppStack = StackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
    const AuthStack = StackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

    export default SwitchNavigator(
      {
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        App: AppStack,
        Auth: AuthStack,
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
      }`enter code here`
    );
```